# preventDefault() not stopping mouseup event on Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I'm trying to detect a mouseup or touchend event without it firing twice. Full example here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#t").on("touchend mouseup", function(e){$("body").append(e.type + "<br>"); e.preventDefault();});
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="t" style="position: absolute; left: 200px; width: 200px; height: 200px; background: blue;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

On a tablet, the touchend event fires first and then after a delay, the mouseup event fires. So I include the e.preventDefault() line and that stops the mouseup event on an iPad as desired. But it has no effect on Android. Both events still fire. Using "return false", stopPropagation(), and/or stopImmediatePropagation() had no effect either. Note that I could just remove the touchend event but I don't want the delay on a tablet waiting for mouseup to fire. And I need to include mouseup for non-tablet devices. I also don't want to test for touch capability and then unbind the mouse support because someone could have a laptop with both touch and mouse support and use them both. I just want Android to stop firing the mouseup event.

Comment: can you try returning false from the callback?

Comment: @bitoiu, I mentioned "return false" in my post. It didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Google had an article about this exact thing a couple years ago, calling it FastButtons. This implementation should do it:

https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons

Comment: I'm not implementing a button control and it doesn't explain why preventDefault is not working with touchend like it does with iOS. However, one thing in that article caught my eye about using preventDefault with touchstart. If I include touchstart in my binding and then ignore it when it fires, preventDefault then stops the mouse events in Android. Still looks like a bug to me. I have an old version of Android (2.2.1) so maybe it's been fixed since then.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem and could find only a very ugly solution: `setTimeout`.

http://jsfiddle.net/FjuHu/6/

```
/**
   * Prevent Android from triggering buggy phantom clicks
   *
   * @param {jQuery} $element
   */
  function preventPhantomClicks($element) {
    /**
     * Click catcher
     * @param {!jQuery.event=} event
     */
    function preventHandler(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    // catch all events for the next 350ms
    $element.on('click', preventHandler);
    setTimeout(function () {
      $element.off('click', preventHandler);
    }, 350);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was wrestling with unwanted events(sudden android mouseups for example).

Since I was listening for touchups and getting unexpected mouseups, my solution was to pass all events into a filter ([node].setEventListener), which would determine if I wanted them to occur, and I'd stop any that I didn't want by setting a custom flag on approved event objects, and preventing/stopping any event that lacked it.

I was able to avoid a timeout this way.  Not elegant but established more control over the system for the time being.